# Rust iterate over borrowed mutable reference

Tags: rust, foreach

I wanted a function to control and change a vector in rust. Here is a simplified version:

```rust
fn foo(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for (i, element) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
        // Some checks here
        vec[(*element) as usize] = i as i32;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2];
    foo(&mut bar);
}
```

This code does not compile because there is both an immutable and a mutable borrow of `vec` in `foo`. I tried getting around this by copying `vec` to a separate copy, which didn't work and also wouldn't have been very pretty. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid borrowing the whole `Vec` by using index access like this:

```
fn foo(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for index in 0..vec.len() {
        let element = vec[index];
        if element <= 0 {
            continue;
        }
        vec[index] = index as i32;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 2];
    foo(&mut bar);
    println!("{:?}", bar)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to mutate the `Vec`, the correct way is to iterate over it *mutably* instead of immutably:

```
fn foo(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    // note the `iter_mut` here:
    for element in vec.iter_mut() {
        // Some checks here
        // element now has type `&mut i32` and we can mutate it directly.
        *element *= 2;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    foo(&mut bar);
    println!("{:?}", bar); // [2, 4, 6]
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to mutate the `Vec` at a certain index and that I cannot just mutate element.

Comment: @gurkensaas Yes you should have mentioned that you have a different question than the one you asked.

Comment: @gurkensaas Nothing stops you from calling `enumerate`, like you did in your immutable example.